# I can't get the .val('') to clear the user input and I have no idea why it isn't working

Tags: jquery, input

So I'm trying to get the text input to clear every time the user submits their input by pressing enter. I've tried `$("#textbox").val('')`, but that doesn't work and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I've also tried `.html('')` and `.text('')`. I have no idea why it isn't working.

Here's my coding.

```js
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $('#start').css('background-color', '#09C');
  });
});

//Item variable//

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function() {
    var input = $("#command").val();
    var check = false;

    if (input == "help") {
      $("#Help").clone().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
      check();
    }


    if (input == "Lombardy East") {
      $("<p class='text'> Great Choice! Close enough to Alexandra to have access to their commuters but far enough not to step on anyone's toes! Now it's time to choose your route. Shall we?</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
      $("<p id='green' class='text'>Let's do this?</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
      check();
      check();
    }

    if (input == "Lyndhurst") {
      $("<p class='text'> It's good enough choice. As long as you don't clash with other drivers on the main road, you should be fine. Now it's time to choose your route. Shall we?</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
      $("<p id='green' class='text'>Okay?</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
      check();
      check();
    }

    if (input == "Orange Grove") {
      $("<p class='text'>Hmmm ... That's a bit close to Louis Botha main road. You might have a few aggressive run ins. Good Luck with that.Now it's time to choose your route. Shall we?</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
      $("<p id='green' class='text'>Sure?</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
      check();
      check();
    }

    if (input == "No") {
      $("<p class='text'> Voetsak! Don't be a wuss!</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
      check();
    }

    if (input == "Yes") {
      var url = "thirdpage.html";
      $(location).attr('href', url);
      check();;
    }

    if (input == "Let's do this") {
      var url = "frthpage.html";
      $(location).attr('href', url);
      check();
    }

    if (input == "Okay") {
      var url = "ffthpage.html";
      $(location).attr('href', url);
      check();
    }

    if (input == "Sure") {
      var url = "sxthpage.html";
      $(location).attr('href', url);
      check();
    } else if (input != "Lombardy East") {
      $("<p class='text'> I do not understand your answer</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
      check();
    }

    $('#command').val("");

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<form onsubmit="return false" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" size="50" autofocus="autofocus" id="command" />
</form>
```

Comment: "I've tried $("#textbox").val('')" -> that is not the input id on your html code.

Comment: Since `check` is `false`, the code will throw an error and at the first `check();` it encounters  and never get as far as `$('#command').val("");`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the way you are trying to clear the input.

```
$('#command').val("");
```

This will work, however you have a javascript error on the page.

The problem is your check variable, you initialize a variable check as a primitive type.

```
var check = false;
```

This is a boolean and not a function. So when you try to invoke the variable check since it is not a function you will get an error.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the check function call, but you have two options.

1.) Remove all the check(); Since check is primitive type (boolean) it can't be invoked as a function.

2.) You could make check a function ...

```
var check = function() {
    // Do Logic here
}
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks. I removed all the check(); and it works. I honestly have no idea what I'm doing with jquery, I'm only just starting with it.